# ASP.NET: ASPX vs ASMX WebMethods to handle AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have this ajax code on Default.aspx:

```
$.ajax({
    //url: "Default.aspx/GetCompany",
    url: "WebService.asmx/GetCompany",
    type: "POST",
    data: { companyName: compName },
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        var jQueryXml = $(data);
        $('#txtBoxInn').val(jQueryXml.find('INN').text());
    }
});
```

When I pass web service url as a parameter, everything works fine. When I pass aspx-page url, nothing happens. Methods' bodies are identical in .asmx and .aspx files.

My question is is it possible to use aspx page instead of asmx service to make ajax request workable?

There is server side code:

```
namespace WSS_AJAX_SQL
{
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public Company GetCompany(string companyName)
        {
            Company company = new Company();

            string cs = @"Data Source=Barrus-laptop\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=WSS_Companies;Integrated Security=True";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"select * from [CompanyList] where [Name] = '{companyName}'", connection);
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    company.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
                    company.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                    company.INN = Convert.ToInt32(reader["INN"]);
                }
            }
            return company;
        }
    }
}
```

Results of console.log:

1. XML format + Web Service (which is working how I desire):

   2
     Microsoft
     994542214
2. XML + Web Page returns the whole page (from !DOCTYPE to /html).
3. JSON + Web Page returns an objest:

```html
Object d: 
  ObjectID: 2
    INN: 994542214
    Name: "Microsoft"
    __type: "WSS_AJAX_SQL.Company"
    __proto__: Object
  __proto__: Object
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it's possible.
In your ASPX page, state a [webmethod]:

```
public partial class Pagename: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static Company GetCompany(string companyName)
    {
        ......
    }
    ...
}
```

Please change:

```
dataType: "xml",
```

to:

```
dataType: "json",
```

Please change:

```
data: { companyName: compName },
```

to:

```
JSON.stringify({ companyName: compName }),
```

Please note the [WebMethod] method needs to be declared `static`.

In your AJAX success method, please change:

```
$('#txtBoxInn').val(jQueryXml.find('INN').text());
```

to:

```
$('#txtBoxInn').val(data.d.INN);
```

Comment: I have this attribute there, but it doesn't work. Is it possible the problem is I try to reach the same page where client-side code is located?

Comment: No, that's not the issue. Could you please share the server side code ?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: Please make the method static. If this does not help, could you please check dev tools in Chrome or IE (F12) to see if any error occours ?

Comment: Chrome gives nothing, IE reports error XML5645 ('The specified entity has not been declared'). When I pass web service, there are no messages in the console window.

Comment: Could you, for now, simplify the success function code just to show an alert? alert('ok');

Comment: I think that you do succeed getting to your webmethod, maybe something is wrong with your success funtcion code... var jQueryXml = $(data);
        $('#txtBoxInn').val(jQueryXml.find('INN').text());

Comment: I added 'error' to $.ajax. When I use Web Service, it succedes, when I use Web Page, it throws an error (Invalid XML).

Comment: Still no. Now it says there is syntax error, but  doesn't specify where. And when I try to use Web Service, it throws Internal Server Error =(

Comment: Try removing  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Comment: I added this: contentType: ` "application/json; charset=utf-8" `. Now it succeedes, but text box remains empty...

Comment: What do you see in Chrome console when you add: console.log(data) to your javascript ?

Comment: Can you share it?

Comment: Please change to: var jQueryXml = $(d.data);    - If that doesnt work, change to var jQueryXml = d.data;

Comment: In both cases it informs 'Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined'

Comment: Oh SNAP ! data.d.. Sorry. You need to change it to data.d

Comment: Error is gone, but the text box is still empty. Shoul I still use this statement:  _$('#txtBoxInn').val(jQueryXml.find('INN').text());_ ?

Comment: Try using $('#txtBoxInn').val(data.INN); or $('#txtBoxInn').val(data.d.INN);

Comment: _val(data.d.INN)_ worked. Jeez it took time. Thanks A LOT Koby, much obliged.

Comment: Great, I'm happy for you. Cheers and good luck from rainy Israel.